# How to detect when window is closed when using Show() in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, show

I've been using ShowDialog() in following way for all my new Windows.

```
SomeGui test = new SomeGui();
test.ShowDialog();
refreshSomeListView();
```

However recently I've started to use Show() instead of ShowDialog() and it's working much better. The only drawback of this is that `refreshSomeListView();` cannot be used like in example above since if i leave it there it's executed instantly when new Window shows up.

What's the best way to know that the user has closed `test` window and that now `refreshSomeListView();` should be executed? What's suggested approach for this? Should it involve setting events in test GUI on Close/Closing or there's other / better method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Form.Closed` event and perform refresh in its handler. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed%28VS.80%29.aspx) is MSDN description of this event.

Comment: Nice, it works. You could update your answer with some code example for future reference.

Comment: Code examples are hardly necessary for basic answers to basic questions.

Comment: Despite Charles not seeing the need, here's link to code example for future reference http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=125

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net:

```
Dim test as new SomeGui()
AddHandler test.Closed, AddressOf refreshSomeListView
test.Show
```